# Sphere with four points deleted

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

What is the universal cover of the sphere with four points deleted and a non-trivial abelian fundamental group?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The 2-sphere with 4 points deleted is the plane with three points deleted which retracts to the bouquet of three circles, so its fundamental group is the free group generated by three elements.

Its universal cover is the plane.